# error: cannot find symbol method getColor(Context,int) after adding Sugar ORM to project

Tags: android, sugarorm, android-orm

I would like to use SugarOrm in my app.

If I add the followings:

```
 compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
```

to the gradle file

and

```
 android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
```

to my mainfest's application name

I get the following error on build:

```
Error:(75, 55) error: cannot find symbol method getColor(Context,int)
```

at this line:

```
 holder.bg.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.primary_move));
```

**If I checkout to a previous version without these 2 lines, my application builds and runds without error.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to compile `'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.6'` and error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html):

> Helper for accessing features in Context introduced after API level 4
>   in a backwards compatible fashion.

Do you really need that backward compatibility?  Try accesing getColor from the context. You can also still use`Context.getColor()` while you resolve the main issue however